# PHP: group array elements by two similar values

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I've got a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [posY] => 5
        [posX] => 48.75
        [id] => 36
    )

 ... 

[5] => Array
    (
        [posY] => 16
        [posX] => 75
        [id] => 15
    )
)
```

I need to group elements with both similar posX and posY values, e.g. in group with posX between 10 and 20, and posY between 5 and 10 will be elements a(11,9), b(14,8), but not c(11, 15) or d(25,20).

The output should be an array like this:

```
 Array 
    (
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 5
                    [posX] => 48.75
                    [id] => 36
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 5
                    [posX] => 52.5
                    [id] => 35
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 5.5
                    [posX] => 18.75
                    [id] => 46
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 7.5
                    [posX] => 52.5
                    [id] => 29
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        ( 
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 15
                    [posX] => 45
                    [id] => 49
                )

             [1] => Array
                (
                    [posY] => 16
                    [posX] => 75
                    [id] => 15
                ) 
        )
    )
```

What's the way of walking though the first array and make groups with elements having both two similar values?

Tnx a lot!

Comment: I tried to sort an initial array by posX, then walk through array and compare each element with previous. If element's posX value not similar to previous one, increase the index of output array element, otherwise index stay the same. The result is output array shown above. But this way I group only by one value, not by both posX and posY.

Comment: this is weird - your definition of similar is different to mine. surely `(19, 9)` is closer to `(21, 11)` than it is `(11, 6)` ?

Comment: @pala_ , yes, a(19, 9) is closer to b(21, 11) then c(11, 6) in my case. "a" & "b" should be grouped, "c" should not be grouped with "a" & "b"

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to calculate the distance between the points, and group them based on cartesian closeness, rather than 'the numbers are close'.  You could do that with something similar to the following (i make no representations that this is in any way optimised):

```
  $points = array(
    array('x' => 48.75, 'y' => 5, 'id' => 36),
    array('x' => 52.5, 'y' => 5, 'id' => 35),
    array('x' => 18.75, 'y' => 5.5, 'id' => 46),
    array('x' => 52.5, 'y' => 7.5, 'id' => 20),
    array('x' => 45, 'y' => 15, 'id' => 49),
    array('x' => 75, 'y' => 16, 'id' => 15)
  );

  // calculate the distances from each point, to all the other points.
  foreach($points as &$p)
  {
    foreach($points as $p2)
    {
      if($p == $p2)
        continue;
      $dist = sqrt(pow($p2['x'] - $p['x'], 2) + pow($p2['y'] - $p['y'], 2));
      if(!isset($p['distances']))
        $p['distances'] = array();
      $p['distances'][$p2['id']] = $dist;
    }
  }

  $res = array();
  $used = array();
  $cnt = -1;

  // find points close to each other
  foreach($points as $p)
  {
    $cnt++;
    if(in_array($p['id'], $used))
      continue;
    foreach($points as $p2)
    {
      if(($p['id'] == $p2['id']) || in_array($p2['id'], $used))
        continue;
      if($p['distances'][$p2['id']] < 5) // 5 is arbitrary definition of closeness
      {
        unset($p2['distances']);
        $res[$cnt][] = $p2;
      }
    }
  }
  print_r($res);
```

the output from this is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 52.5
                    [y] => 5
                    [id] => 35
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 52.5
                    [y] => 7.5
                    [id] => 20
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 48.75
                    [y] => 5
                    [id] => 36
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 52.5
                    [y] => 7.5
                    [id] => 20
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 48.75
                    [y] => 5
                    [id] => 36
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 52.5
                    [y] => 5
                    [id] => 35
                )

        )

)
```

This won't necessarily give you all elements grouped / paired with the element it is CLOSEST to, but it will ensure that all elements are with a certain distance of each other.